# Is a cover a good idea for keeping a large outdoor propane tank cool?

Tags: propane, temperature, cover

I live in a state where the temps are starting to climb each summer, last year breaking 118°F in my city. The large propane tank I have for my house says to not exceed 120 and I read that pressure can build if such is the case. It's covered by shade for half the day but the other half the sun heats it up real quick.

I searched online for Propane Tank Covers but I've only seen small and medium. Is it pointless to get a cover for a Large tank or is there somewhere that sells them or maybe custom sells them? Sorry if it's dumb, please help thank you!

Comment: Welcome. What exactly is "large"? Please take the [tour].

Comment: A cover/shade is good to keep the sun off and the extra heating from the sun.  Real air temperature(not from a thermometer in the sun) is different and a cover will not help.   Ask your propane supplier.  If lucky there is a safety factor built in the 120 rating, like only run at 160, instead of 130.

Comment: Those tanks usually have a pressure relief valve to prevent bursting.

Comment: Just don't flick your bic if the relief valve is open.  Guess the youngsters won't get this.

Answer (score 1):

### White paint reflects solar gain

It can help to paint the tank Snow White (the whitest paint your supplier has) - that has an 82% albedo (reflectivity) and can get rid of a lot of that sun.

As soon as you even start to tint the white, albedo drops like a stone. The typical pastels used on houses have <50% albedo (terrible). Most roofs are below 10% albedo.

There's a lot of nonsense on the web about super-whites, and light silver, and other stuff. Give me a break.

The tank is going to equalize at ambient *air* temperature even if you build a shade structure around it.  Direct sun will cause *solar gain*, which is about 1000 watts per square meter or 300 BTU/hr per square foot, *minus albedo*.  That's where snow white paint is a winner.

### Now here's an interesting fact about propane.

It's stored as a liquid but you take it as a gas, **which means it must *evaporate (approximately: boil)***.  Ever put a pot of water on the stove? It reaches boiling quickly but then takes a long time to boil. That's because it only takes 150 BTU to get a pound of water to boiling, (1 BTU per pound per degree F), but another 1000 BTU to actually turn it from 212F liquid to 212F vapor.  That is *latent heat of vaporization*, or *enthalpy* if we're trying to fit in with the science types :)

Propane too has a latent heat of vaporization, ranging from 140 to 180 BTUs per pound of propane.  When propane boils, it "steals" those BTUs from the other propane in the tank, making it cooler.  This can be a problem in the coldest winter conditions because it can pull the propane below its natural boiling point, reducing pressure to zero.

But "using propane chills the tank" works in your favor in summer. Every pound of propane you use removes 140 BTU from the tank.  Propane's heat capacity is only 42% of water, so those 140 BTUs cools 332 pounds of propane by 1 degree F.

So "use a lot of propane" is one way to cool the tank somewhat.

You might think, why not make a propane compressor that takes propane as vapor, compresses it (heating it), run it through a condenser to shed that heat to turn it into liquid and shove it back into the tank, repeat endlessly?  Well yes, that is the refrigeration cycle used in fridges and air conditioners, and it would be that easy. (hey, a lot of fridges and window A/Cs use R290 = propane!)  I'm not aware of any propane tank coolers which do that, but it's a fun idea.)

### So we learn...

A "jacket" by itself does nothing but look pretty. Solar gain is going to make the heat, **unless you reflect it with white color**, and without insulation much of it will reach the tank. You would be better off with a shade with some standoff distance from the tank, so that air on the shady side of the shade cools the shade and prevents the solar gain *on the shade* from reaching the tank.

That said, thick insulation will have a multiplicative effect, since it will *not only* slow the heating of the tank, but also help the tank "keep" the "latent heat of vaporization" cooling it gets during propane usage. *Of course, in winter that insulation will be your worst enemy*, so it will need to be removed, or else an electric heater added between tank and insulation. Your supplier of propane and propane accessories should be able to set you up with a tank heater.

Comment: IMHO It doesn't need to actually boil, it needs to evaporate. I think boiling propane would be a bad thingy.

Comment: @George wait, what's the difference?

Comment: Water can evaporate w/o boiling as can many other liquids such as denatured alcohol, gasoline, acetone, etc.  Propane doesn't need to "boil" in order to vaporize.  Just the right combo of pressure and temperature. Actual boiling propane would scare the crap out of me.

Comment: @George Propane melts at -306F, and boils at -44F (at normal temp/pressure).  Increasing pressure [raises boiling point](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/propane-vapor-pressure-d_1020.html).  When pressure falls putting the temperature of the propane above boiling point for its new pressure, it must vaporize, raising pressure, and that cools the mass by its latent heat of vaporization. Together these reach that equilibrium line and stop. But yes, uncontrolled it is a BLEVE which is terrifying! Just the first part, I mean. The second part, when it finds a flame source, is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to hot summer.

We have close to 115F outside air temperature.

However the surfaces exposed to Sun will absorb heat and could go to 140F.

Isolation is good, but it will not lover it below air temperature just prevent heat absorption. The delta from air to surface temperature.

Thus a simple shade would already help some, but a true isolation blanket is better.

Data from my home measured with infrared thermometer on sun exposed walls, and walls in shade. The walls are stucco, thus not so heat absorbent as metal.